# Textarea in Fieldset leaves a bottom gap

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, textarea, fieldset

I'm trying to figure out why Chrome leaves a bottom gap when using a textarea within a fieldset tag.

If you look at the following fiddle with Chrome you will hopefully see what I mean

https://jsfiddle.net/552aamop/1/

The fiddle CSS contains Eric Meyers standard reset, and I've reset the margin and padding on the input and textarea tags. The HTML contains no whitespace between the elements.

```
<form>
<fieldset><input type='text'/></fieldset>
<fieldset><input type='text'/></fieldset>
<fieldset><textarea>Hello</textarea></fieldset>
<fieldset><textarea>Hello</textarea></fieldset>
</form>
```

Firefox and IE seem to render with no gap between the fieldset. Chrome leaves a gap, but will only leave a gap if the fieldset contains a textarea. Any idea why?

I'm using Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `font: inherit;` at the base. Chrome is adding its default line-height. It appears Firefox has a default line-height of 1.1, but Chrome has a default line-height of 1.2.

Shorthand: `font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;`

This will fix your problem.

```
fieldset{ line-height:0}
```

Checkout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/552aamop/5/):

Comment: Thanks, this worked best for me. I moved the line-height declaration to the   text area tag though so as not to affect any other elements.

Answer (score 1):

The fieldsets don't leave a gap between themselves - rather the textarea inside doesn't fill them put completely. The Reason for this is that the textarea has the default property of "display: inline-block", wich means its height will be defined by whats inside. I Think the other part is that Chrome gives it a min height.

So i would propose you get the Textarea the css the property "display:block" so it fills the height of its container.

Comment: Yeah, this does fix this, but I want a label tag next to the textarea without floating, so this wouldn't be a solution for the site i'm doing, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the other answers, giving `vertical-align:middle` to the textarea element works as well.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  /* this works as well */
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset><input type='text' /></fieldset>
  <fieldset><input type='text' /></fieldset>
  <fieldset><textarea>Hello</textarea></fieldset>
  <fieldset><textarea>Hello</textarea></fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**using** `display: flex;` **worked all browser same output**

```
fieldset{
    display: flex;
}
```

**or**

```
input, textarea{
        display: flex;
    }
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
fieldset{
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<fieldset><input type='text'/></fieldset>
<fieldset><input type='text'/></fieldset>
<fieldset><textarea>Hello</textarea></fieldset>
<fieldset><textarea>Hello</textarea></fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi, Flex is not really an option, its not fully supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem:

Every browser has a custom way of showing elements. Chrome sets display: block and some webkit margins but overriding them doesn't work.

```
fieldset {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-start: 2px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 2px;
    -webkit-padding-before: 0.35em;
    -webkit-padding-start: 0.75em;
    -webkit-padding-end: 0.75em;
    -webkit-padding-after: 0.625em;
    min-width: -webkit-min-content;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: threedface;
    border-image: initial;
}
```

> Solution:

```
fieldset {
        display: flex;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You should add following statement in your css.

`<style>
  fieldset {padding: 0px;}
</style>`